# Swift 2 to Swift 2.3 guard let and for errors

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, swift2

I have working project but when opened it gives me simple 3 errors. Here is my code:

1

```
   let location, let response, let error) in
        
        guard let _:NSURL = location, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }
```

and errors

> 'let' as a parameter attribute is not allowed,  Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition ,

2

```
for constraint in self.contentView.constraints {
      if let item = constraint.firstItem as? UIView where item == containerView {
        let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint( item: anAnimationView, attribute: constraint.firstAttribute,
          relatedBy: constraint.relation, toItem: constraint.secondItem, attribute: constraint.secondAttribute,
          multiplier: constraint.multiplier, constant: constraint.constant)
        
        newConstraints.append(newConstraint)
      } else if let item: UIView = constraint.secondItem as? UIView where item == containerView {
        let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: constraint.firstItem, attribute: constraint.firstAttribute,
          relatedBy: constraint.relation, toItem: anAnimationView, attribute: constraint.secondAttribute,
          multiplier: constraint.multiplier, constant: constraint.constant)
        
        newConstraints.append(newConstraint)
      }
    }
```

and errors

> Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition ( where )

3

```
    func removeAllSubViews(){
        for (var i = 0 ; i < subviews.count ; i++){
            subviews[i].removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    
    func loadViewFromNib(nibName:String) -> UIView {
        
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        let v = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        
        return v
    }
    
}
```

Error

> '.dynamicType' is deprecated. Use 'type(of: ...)' instead

I tried everything but I wasn't able to resolve this.

Comment: Instead of `where` use `,`. Instead of `self.dynamicType` use `type(of:)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

```
(location, response, error) in
    guard error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
// In this scope `location` and `response` are optional but guaranteed not `nil`
```

or

```
(location, response, error) in
    guard let loc = location, let resp = response, error == nil else {
        print(error!)
        return
    }
```

2)

```
if let item = constraint.firstItem as? UIView, item == containerView {
```

3)

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: type(of:self))
```

*4*) The Swift way of `removeAllSubViews` is (no ugly C-style loops)

```
func removeAllSubViews() { subViews.forEach{ $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3, there has been quite a few changes.

> 1. 'let' as a parameter attribute is not allowed, Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition ,

Every assignment operation you do in `guard` or `if let` statements should be prefixed with appropriate `let` or `var` and should be separated by comma.

> 2. Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition ( where )

`where` clause cannot be used in `guard` statements anymore. You can just remove the `where` and replace it with `,` separator.

> 3. '.dynamicType' is deprecated. Use 'type(of: ...)' instead

Method signature `.dynamicType` has been changed to `type(of: )`. So update your code to use `type(of:)` instead of `dynamicType`